# Can you link to permalink Bug Events in FogBugz the same way you can Cases?

Tags: hyperlink, case, fogbugz

For instance if I type Case XXXX into FogBugs, I'll end up with link within the case.

But what if I want to link to specific Bug Event within the Issue?

Comment: Also, you probably want to ask questions like these on fogbugz.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.  Click on the timestamp in the bug event that you want to link to and use that link. (e.g. "4/1/2011 7:27 PM" in the screenshot below.)

[image]

Comment: So you just use the entire perma-link, there isn't a way specify it like "In Case 12331:BugEvent13221" ?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, does it? The answer is actually, "No, there is no smarts in FB to dynamically link to a bugevent number". You will have to copy the absolute url to the bugevent.